# Choose the order in which columns are displayed when hidden (under the green plus sign) in DataTables in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

## Context

When making an interactive table using the DataTables library, columns are hidden under a green + sign when the screen width becomes too narrow for the number and width of columns. I have a very wide table with more than 20 columns, some with very wordy contents, so some columns are always hidden at all screen widths.

Each time a new column is hidden, it is added to the top of this list, meaning that as the screen becomes narrower, these columns that were hidden first get pushed to the bottom.

## Question

I would like a particular column to remain at the top of this list all the time.

As a broader question, is it possible to control the order of the hidden ‘columns’ in this list under the green plus sign? I know it is possible to control the order in which columns are hidden as the screen narrows (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436071/specify-the-order-in-which-columns-are-hidden-in-datatables-in-r)), but have not found a way to choose the order of these columns once hidden.

## Example code

For example, say I would like my ‘description’ column (which has a short paragraph of text for each row of the table) to remain at the top of this ‘hidden’ section, with new columns being displayed below it as they are hidden. Currently, on narrow screens, it gets pushed to the bottom of a long list of hidden columns.

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(column_1 = 1:10, 
             column_2 = rep(1,10), 
             column_3 = rep("some text"),
             column_4 = seq(2,29,3),
             column_5 = 5:14,
             description = rep("Here is some very long and wordy text. I would like this text to remain hidden under the green + sign that appears when the screen becomes narrow. In real life, I have many more columns than this, and want as many of them to display as possible, but this column to remain hidden even with a very wide screen.", 10))

datatable(df,
      extensions = "Responsive")`
```

Note: I am using the R DT library in flexdashboard, but I expect this question is relevant for other uses of DataTables (e.g. in javascript).

### See also these 2 related questions:

- [Specify the order in which columns are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436071/specify-the-order-in-which-columns-are-hidden-in-datatables-in-r)
- [Specify columns to remain hidden at all times and all screen widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616265/specify-columns-to-remain-hidden-at-all-times-and-all-screen-widths-in-datatable)