# Specify columns to remain hidden at all times and all screen widths in DataTables in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

## Question

When making an interactive table using the DataTables library, columns are hidden under a green + sign when the screen width becomes too narrow for the number and width of columns. Is it possible to specify column(s) to remain hidden at all times – even if the screen is wide enough to display them?

I am using the R DT library in flexdashboard, but I expect this question is relevant for other uses of DataTables (e.g. in javascript).

## Example code

In the example below, I would like column_5 to remain hidden at all times:

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(column_1 = 1:10, 
             column_2 = rep(1,10), 
             column_3 = rep("some text"),
             column_4 = seq(2,29,3),
             column_5 = 5:14)

datatable(df,
      extensions = "Responsive",
      options = list(columnDefs = list(
        list(responsivePriority = 9999999999, targets = 5)
      )))
```

I have tried setting its priority to be hidden to a very large number (using the same idea as explained by @andrewJames [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76436215/20935707)), but this doesn’t work if the screen is wide enough to display all 5 columns.

### See also these 2 related questions:

- [Choose the order in which columns are displayed when hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76615996/choose-the-order-in-which-columns-are-displayed-when-hidden-under-the-green-plu)
- [Specify the order in which columns are hidden in DataTables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436071/specify-the-order-in-which-columns-are-hidden-in-datatables-in-r)

Comment: this might be handy: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class name "none" to force the column to always be hidden. To be clear, the data is still visible by clicking on the green plus icon.

[DataTables - Reference](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes#:%7E:text=the%20default%20breakpoints.-,Special%20classes,-In%20addition%20to)

```
datatable(
  df,
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = "Responsive",
  options = list(columnDefs = list(
    list(className = "none", targets = 4)
  ))
)
```

If you don't want the column and data associated with the column to be visible you can use the `visible` arg.

```
columnDefs = list(
  list(visible = FALSE, targets = your_cols)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie; this is exactly what I was looking for :) Just to note for other people reading this question - columns hidden via this method always appear at the top of the list under the green plus sign. As the screen gets narrower, new columns are listed beneath. You can't control the order in which the columns hidden via this method are listed (targets = c(2,4) is the same as targets = c(4,2), with column 2 listed above column 4) but changing the order of columns in the original data frame will achieve this. Thanks again!